# How do I add text to a record when inserting from php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this statement to add information to a database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (manufacturer, name, url) VALUES ('{$_POST['manufacturer']}','{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['url']}')";
var_dump($sql);
```

I would like to add `http://webaddress.com/` before the `$_POST['url']`. So if I enter in file name example it will go into the record as `http://webaddress.com/example`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: This is simply a matter of concatenating the url prefix before the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to concatenate your string and your variable

```
"INSERT INTO test1 (manufacturer, name, url) VALUES ('".$_POST['manufacturer']."','".$_POST['name']."', 'http://webaddress.com/".$_POST['url']."')";
```

As side note I would like you to focus your attention on [`sql injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) since your code is vulnerable and you are at risk

Comment: The new statement works. I have the sql injection prevention added a little bit higher at the top. I have a question about what you did though. I did what you did with the webaddress but it didn't work. It looks like you added a . before each of the other $_POST that I did not. What you did works but I wanted to keep the data from the other 2 forms the same so I didn't touch those. If one thing is concatenated in a statement does that mean everything needs the .?

Comment: But I only wanted to concatenate the url one not the others. What you did works, I am just trying to understand why.

Comment: You can either concatenate only the url then

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, that is when I came here.